# Prevent file corruption when saving xml file

Tags: c#, .net

Next line sometimes is corrupting xml file and creating a zero length xml, when OutOfMemoryException has been thrown. How to prevent file corruption?

```
xmlDoc.Save(filename)
```

> Save-Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>   Save-at System.IO.FileStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32
>   count)    at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean
>   flushEncoder)    at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char value)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.Indent(Boolean beforeEndElement)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.AutoComplete(Token token)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String
>   localName, String ns)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlDOMTextWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String
>   localName, String ns)    at System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)
>   at System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter xw)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename)    at
>   MainOptions.Save(String filename, ItemOptions options)

Comment: It depends on a number of factors such as the size of the document you are attempting to save or whether it has errors or not.  There's no way we can tell you based on what you've shown us.  You'll need to show us some code and the XML you are trying to save.

Comment: File is not so big 5Kb, and is saved frequently due to item options updates; error with individual option updates will not cause file corruption; only error during save will do that

Comment: What do you want to prevent, overwritting the previous copy or the error itself?

Comment: file corruption, overwriting with null string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overwritting the file as you save it to `filename`.
To backup the old copy,

- move it to another location (like `filename.bak`) before saving and
  delete it afterwards *or*
- save the new file as another file (like `filename.new`) and rename it on success

When an exception is thrown, you can easily restore the old/previous version of the xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with [Matten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524475/matten). Alternative solution can be generating xml string before saving it to a file:

```
Using ms As New MemoryStream
    xmlDoc.Save(ms)
    Using outStream As FileStream = File.Open(filename,
                 FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
        ms.WriteTo(outStream)
    End Using
End Using
```

Use stream to match xmlDoc.Save(filename)

Answer (score 1):

[OutOfMemory Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1766918e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

This exception can be thrown by the common language runtime when there is not enough memory to allocate for internal purposes or new object instances. To avoid this exception, **avoid programming large methods that consume 64 or more kilobytes of memory.**

So one possible reason could be the method in which you are saving your XML Document is trying to allocate more than 64KB.

To avoid corruption 'Matten' answer is good enough also Jon skeet suggests same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130834/overwriting-a-document-file).

But I will like to add further safety checks by using locks while doing this operation

```
  private static readonly object locker = new object();

  public static void OnlyOneCallerAllowed()
  {
    lock (locker)
    {
     string tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
     xmlDoc.Save(tempFileName);
     File.Move(original_file, original_file.old);
     File.Move(tempFileName,original_file);
     File.Delete( tempFileName);
    }
  }
```

Comment: 64 kilobytes? Don't believe everything you read on the internet! If there is a 64k limit, it isn't on _allocation_.

Comment: @JasonWilliams fair point , How can we prove MSDN is lying ;) then we can post our data on MSDN under Community Content.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the OutOfMemory exception ...

If you document is large and has child elements going a few levels deep then the indenting can bloat the file size. I've found that XmlDocument with XmlTextWriter indents using spaces. I've

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.formatting%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Try disabling all indenting and see if this helps. If it does consider 1 character indenting and restructuring the file.

Comment: Yes, you are right that should save some space. But that is a part of bigger work to do (solving OutOfMemory exception)